# How to configure Spring SAML to send "assertionConsumerServiceIndex" instead of "assertionConsumerServiceUrl"?

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml, saml-2.0

How can I configure Spring SAML to send "**assertionConsumerServiceIndex**" instead of "**assertionConsumerServiceUrl**" in the SAML Authentication Requests?

Another question:
Where can I report an issue of the Spring security SAML project?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working but not through config file. I found following comment in the Spring SAML source code:

```java
// AssertionConsumerServiceURL + ProtocolBinding is mutually exclusive with AssertionConsumerServiceIndex, we use first one here
```

I had to modify `buildReturnAddress` method of `WebSSOProfileImpl` class as below to insert `AssertionConsumerServiceIndex` instead of `AssertionConsumerServiceURL + ProtocolBinding` when creating new AuthNRequest:

```java
if (service != null) {
    request.setAssertionConsumerServiceIndex(service.getIndex());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, We need to alter the way `buildReturnAddress()` behaves in f/w. We can do this  simply by extending `WebSSOProfileImpl` and overriding `buildReturnAddress()` method in our service provider code.